# ¿ set_time_limit() funciona independiente si llamo otro código php que lo tenga ? - PHP

Tags: php

tengo esta duda, y no se como comprobarla, pasaré a explicar mi problema.

Existe un código PHP (no es mío y se que existe)
Este código, **NO TIENE UN** `set_time_limit` explícito, y no se si hay forma de obtenerlo.

Ahora, este primer código, llama un segundo código, con el uso de `include()`
Este segundo código, si es mío, y le he dado un `set_time_limit()` definido.

Entonces, mi duda e ignorancia, viene en la siguente parte...

¿Qué sucede en este caso?
El time limit del primer PHP sobre-escribe el mío ???
O el mío es independiente del primero, a pesar de estar incluido ??

Dejo un ejemplo de código para que se entienda.

```
<?php
  //Codigo1.php
  [........]
  include("codigo2.php");
?>
```

.

```
<?php
  //Codigo2.php
  set_time_limit(300);
  [........]
?>
```

Comment: El tuyo será independiente y tu script podrá durar 300 segundos, el script (Codigo1.php) al llamar a Codigo2.php tomará el limit de la configuración de php.ini, y  en este caso se tomará el time limit de quien realice la primera petición (Codigo1.php)

Comment: Entonces, si fuese default (creo que 30seg), entonces le primer código duraría 30 seg y el 2do, 300 ??

Comment: Si, pero si el primero llama al segundo todo el proceso solo durará 30 segundo porque se toma la configuración del primero.

Comment: Entonces, de que modo puedo saber cuanto demora el primer código, y cuanto demora el 2do ?? Por que creo que el 1ro está recortando el tiempo del 2do